# Cordova - how to set in app localisations for display on the Google Play Store

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app I use a Cordova plugin for iOS `cordova-plugin-ios-localized-strings` where I can specify the languages supported by my app. I'm not talking about the Stores descriptions, nor about the technique to handle multiple languages in my app. There must an Android equivalent, something in the apk file telling which languages are supported so it would display on the Google Play Store?